# What's in the .gem specs marshal stuff in my local personal dir?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, rbenv

I'm using rbenv and ruby-build with bundler, and I see a .gem file in my local personal directory, which is confusing because I thought that setting a local ruby using rbenv along with using bundler would keep all my gems in the local project file, not my local personal directory.

Did I install something incorrectly?  Can I delete the .gem dir in my local personal dir?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are there actually any gems in ~/.gem ? If not, you can delete it. To prevent any future installations there, you can create an empty dir and chmod 500 on it.

See my other answer for why this dir even exists:
[I'm using rbenv, so why are there two Gem paths on my system? (OS X Lion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432470/im-using-rbenv-so-why-are-there-two-gem-paths-on-my-system-os-x-lion/10558244#10558244)